# A random tricky question about conservation of momentum

Tags: momentum

I was thinking while trying to sleep and I suddenly asked myself the following question. I couldn't figure out the answer.

**Question:** Think that we are in space with a ball (or particle) and an inclined plane (the angle of the plane doesn't matter). Imagine that the ball is coming through the plane with a constant velocity $\vec{v}_i=-v\hat{i}$. And then the ball hits plane and bounces with some velocity $\vec{v}_f=v_x\hat{i}+v_y\hat{j}$. Consider that the inclined plane doesnt move, It's attached someway. So, linear momentum of the system before the ball hits plane is equal to $\vec{p}_i=m\vec{v}_i=mv\hat{i}$ and the linear momentum if the system after the ball bounces equal to $\vec{p}_f=m\vec{v}_f=m(v_x\hat{i}+v_y\hat{j})=mv_x\hat{i}+mv_y\hat{j}$. $\vec{p}_i\ne\vec{p}_f$. Seems like the momentum is not conserved by some reason. What's the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For two or more bodies in an isolated system acting upon each other, their total momentum remains constant unless an external force is applied. Therefore, momentum can neither be created nor destroyed.

Momentum is conserved for a system only when an isolated system does not have any external forces acting on it.
In your example, if you consider the ball and inclined plane as a system, the external force is the attachment of the inclined plane that stops it's movement; Since it is provided my something that is not part of the system.

As another thought experiment, if the inclined plane was in free floating space, and the ball hits the plane, the plane would definitely move according to the conservation of momentum in the other direction.

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with space, bounce a ball against any wall and momentum seems not preserved. but by  saying "It's attached someway" you give it + the attachment infinit mass or at least very large mass compared to the ball.Call your plank a massiv object.

Answer (score 1):

In such case conservation of momentum does not hold in every direction. Like perpendicular to the plane of inclined plane, there will be a normal force which here acts as an impulsive force so momentum is not conserved in y direction due to this impulsive force ,it will only be conserved along the horizontal direction